# Is there a public record of planetary disks apart from ours?

Tags: exoplanet

Our planetary disk is not aligned with the rest of the galaxy.  Are there publicly available records of the orientations of any other planetary disks?

Especially interested in nearby stars - but I'd expect that to be easier for us to measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A useful resource for protoplanetary discs is the recent DSHARP survey using the ALMA telescope. With the ALMA telescope the spatial resolution is good enough that orientation (i.e. position angle and inclination) can be derived from the images.

See [here](https://almascience.eso.org/almadata/lp/DSHARP/).